# Flutter Xcode error building, framework not found uv, Linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, xcode, build, package, dependencies

I get this error when doing build in the Xcode to either the physical device or the simulator.[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jlifj.png). If. anyone has a solution,

here goes my flutter doctor
[Flutter Doctor screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQZVn.png)

```
platform :ios, '15'

ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_modular_headers!
  use_frameworks! :linkage => :static

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))

  pod 'MLKitVision', :podspec => 'MLKitVision.podspec.json'
  pod 'MLKitCommon', :podspec => 'MLKitCommon.podspec.json'
end

post_install do |installer|
  projects = installer.aggregate_targets
   .map{ |t| t.user_project }
   .uniq{ |p| p.path }
   .push(installer.pods_project)
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
   end

  projects.each do |project|
   project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] =
   'arm64'
   end

   project.save()
 end
 end
```

here goes part of my log

-ObjC -lBROTHERSDK -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AVFoundation -framework Accelerate -framework BRLMPrinterKit -framework BROTHERSDK -framework CoreBluetooth -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreImage -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreVideo -framework FBLPromises -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseAppCheckInterop -framework FirebaseAuth -framework FirebaseAuthInterop -framework FirebaseCore -framework FirebaseCoreExtension -framework FirebaseCoreInternal -framework FirebaseCrashlytics -framework FirebaseDynamicLinks -framework FirebaseFirestore -framework FirebaseFunctions -framework FirebaseInstallations -framework FirebaseMessaging -framework FirebaseMessagingInterop -framework FirebaseSessions -framework FirebaseSharedSwift -framework FirebaseStorage -framework Foundation -framework GTMSessionFetcher -framework GoogleAppMeasurement -framework GoogleAppMeasurementIdentitySupport -framework GoogleDataTransport -framework GoogleToolboxForMac -framework GoogleUtilities -framework GoogleUtilitiesComponents -framework LocalAuthentication -framework MLImage -framework MLKitBarcodeScanning -framework MLKitCommon -framework MLKitVision -framework Mapbox -framework MapboxAnnotationExtension -framework MapboxMobileEvents -framework Promises -framework Protobuf -framework QuartzCore -framework Reachability -framework SafariServices -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework absl -framework another_brother -framework app_settings -framework camera_avfoundation -framework cloud_firestore -framework cloud_functions -framework connectivity_plus -framework firebase_analytics -framework firebase_auth -framework firebase_core -framework firebase_crashlytics -framework firebase_dynamic_links -framework firebase_messaging -framework firebase_storage -framework flutter_blue_plus -framework grpc -framework grpcpp -framework image_picker_ios -framework leveldb -framework mapbox_gl -framework mobile_scanner -framework nanopb -framework nfc_manager -framework open_mail_app -framework openssl_grpc -framework path_provider_foundation -framework permission_handler_apple -framework shared_preferences_foundation -framework url_launcher_ios -weak_framework UserNotifications -weak_framework WebKit -ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AVFoundation -framework Accelerate -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreImage -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreVideo -framework FBLPromises -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseAppCheckInterop -framework FirebaseAuth -framework FirebaseAuthInterop -framework FirebaseCore -framework FirebaseCoreExtension -framework FirebaseCoreInternal -framework FirebaseCrashlytics -framework FirebaseDynamicLinks -framework FirebaseFirestore -framework FirebaseFunctions -framework FirebaseInstallations -framework FirebaseMessaging -framework FirebaseMessagingInterop -framework FirebaseSessions -framework FirebaseSharedSwift -framework FirebaseStorage -framework Foundation -framework GTMSessionFetcher -framework GoogleAppMeasurement -framework GoogleAppMeasurementIdentitySupport -framework GoogleDataTransport -framework GoogleToolboxForMac -framework GoogleUtilities -framework GoogleUtilitiesComponents -framework LocalAuthentication -framework MLImage -framework MLKitBarcodeScanning -framework MLKitCommon -framework MLKitVision -framework Mapbox -framework MapboxAnnotationExtension -framework MapboxMobileEvents -framework Promises -framework Protobuf -framework QuartzCore -framework Reachability -framework SafariServices -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework absl -framework app_settings -framework camera_avfoundation -framework cloud_firestore -framework cloud_functions -framework connectivity_plus -framework firebase_analytics -framework firebase_auth -framework firebase_core -framework firebase_crashlytics -framework firebase_dynamic_links -framework firebase_messaging -framework firebase_storage -framework grpc -framework grpcpp -framework image_picker_ios -framework leveldb -framework mapbox_gl -framework mobile_scanner -framework nanopb -framework nfc_manager -framework open_mail_app -framework openssl_grpc -framework shared_preferences_foundation -framework url_launcher_ios -framework uv -weak_framework UserNotifications -weak_framework WebKit -framework CoreNFC -framework Pods_Runner -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/andrecoelho/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-davupscvuiscftaifzgktahdvish/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-dev-iphoneos/Runner.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Runner_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/andrecoelho/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-davupscvuiscftaifzgktahdvish/Build/Products/Debug-dev-iphoneos/Runner.app/Runner

ld: framework not found uv
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)